# ¿Cómo seleccionar una etiqueta en una lista de nodos?

Tags: javascript

He creado una fachada para unos items en general los cuales tienen en un sector un boton para agregar al carrito de compras; ya que algunos items no deben tener ese botón surge la necesidad de quitar de los items que cumplan cierta condición ese botón y poner otro botón el cuál ya se encuentra definido.

Como los items se cargan desde una base de datos en un archivo javascript estoy creando una función para ejecutarla después de que se ha cargado los elementos del DOM.

Lo que tengo por el momento en el javascript:

```
window.onload(detectCot());

function detectCot(){
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName('img-trj-prod');
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let cadenaId = items[i].getAttribute('id');
        let aux = cadenaId.split(',');
        if (aux[5] == 5 ) {            
            let listaNodos = items[i].parentNode.childNodes[5] ;
           console.log(listaNodos);
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

hasta allí he logrado acceder a ver en consola todos los nodos que conforman la fachada; lo que no se es como seleccionar una etiqueta `<a>` (que es la que contiene adentro el botón) para poder eliminarla y luego insertar otro pedazo de código.

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar la etiqueta  debes utilizar el siguiente código:

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Comment: Claro, tienes razón en la selección de una etiqueta. No me queda claro si aumentando la línea de código solo seleccione la etiqueta deseada dentro de la lista de los nodos.